# Create JSONObject dynamically Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a project in SpringBoot and I am looking to create a JSON object to send to my FrontEnd project, I am looking to create a JSON like this:

```
{    "result": {    "data": [      {        "month": "January",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "February",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "March",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "April",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "May",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "June",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "July",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "August",        "APERTURAS": 3      },      {        "month": "September",        "APERTURAS": 11      },      {        "month": "October",        "APERTURAS": 3      },      {        "month": "November",        "APERTURAS": 0      },      {        "month": "December",        "APERTURAS": 0      }    ]    }    }
```

in this one, amounts are being totaled per month, I am making a query and with this I obtain the months in which there is information, I need to create the json with the information of all the months of the year, but if for example the query does not return the amount of a specific month or months, I want to indicate this in zero.

with my code I am getting the following JSON:

```
{  "result": {    "data": [      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {        "APERTURAS": 0,        "month": "August"      },      {},      {},      {},      {        "APERTURAS": 0,        "month": "September"      },      {},      {},      {},      {        "APERTURAS": 3,        "month": "October"      },      {},      {},      {},      {},      {},      {}    ]  }}
```

This is my code:

```
private static final String[] MESES_COMPLETO = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

List<ReporteTipoActoMesInterfaceDTO> resultadoAperturas = repositorioReporte.reporteTipoActoAperturaMes(String.valueOf(year));

List<Object> reporteList = new ArrayList<Object>();     
JSONObject reporteJson = new JSONObject();

for (int j = 0; j < MESES_COMPLETO.length; j++) {

JSONObject reporteJson = new JSONObject();
            
for (int k = 0; k < resultadoAperturas.size(); k++) {
    JSONObject reporteJson2 = new JSONObject();
    String mes = resultadoAperturas.get(k).getmes().replaceAll("\\s+","");
                
    if (!MESES_COMPLETO[j].equals(mes)) {                       
        reporteJson.put("month", MESES_COMPLETO[j]);
        reporteJson.put("APERTURAS", 0);
        reporteList.add(reporteJson2);
    } 
    else {

        if (Arrays.asList(MESES_COMPLETO[j]).contains(mes)) {

            reporteJson.put("month", mes);
            reporteJson.put("APERTURAS", resultadoAperturas.get(k).getexpedientes());
            reporteList.add(reporteJson);
        }
    }
}
}       
        
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
jsonData.put("data", reporteList);
        
jsonResponse = new JSONObject().put("result", jsonData).toString();
```

This is DTO

```
public interface ReporteTipoActoMesInterfaceDTO {

Long getexpedientes();

String getmes();
}
```

This is the result of the query

```
EXPEDIENTES MES
3           August    
11          September
3           October
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it looks like there's no real reason to do manual JSON construction via `JSONObject`s.

Just define your DTOs to match the desired JSON structure, fill it with your data and use Jackson to serialize it altogether.

DTOs:

```java
    @Data
    class ResultDto {
        DataDto result;

        @Data
        static class DataDto {
            List<MonthDataDto> data;
        }

        @Data
        static class MonthDataDto {
            String month;
            @JsonProperty("APERTURAS")
            Integer aperturas;
        }
    }
```

Serialization:

```java
ResultDto resultDto = ...
String jsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(resultDto);
```

Be sure to have `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` dependency in your project.